# Redirect audio from one windows computer to another computer

Tags: windows-10, audio, audio-streaming, dlna

I would like to redirect audio from a specific application on a Windows 10 computer to another Windows 10 computer.

I don't want to use RDP or any kind of remote desktop application - I want to redirect the audio directly to the other computer.

I tried setting it up using [SWYH](https://www.streamwhatyouhear.com/) but I couldn't do that since there is no option to select the input application or device.

I also tried using [VAC 4.51](http://www.ntonyx.com/vac.htm) but I can't figure out how to connect the audio repeater output to the virtual cable on the other computer.

I'm not looking for a solution that forces me to use a specific program (like VNC and such) but something more in the driver level that will allow me to decide which program on the local computer will output the audio to the other computer.

Any ideas how to configure this or any programs that can do this?

Comment: I've used https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/ .

Comment: @davidmneedham - Ahh, interesting. I didn't know Rogue Amoeba made anything for Windows. Their Mac stuff is amazing.

Comment: @davidmneedham I tried it now, it seems to make programs freeze (not all of course, it works with Chrome, but crashes for example MusicBee and MS Groove).